# Code broken in a particular order

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been a designer by trade for years however I am working with WordPress for a client and have been managing to get by with working with hooks... I am, however now at a standstill.

On the homepage I have two areas which will be pulling information from the database:

```
<?php 
    $thumb_posts = get_posts(array('category' => '6', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'numberposts' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' ));
if($thumb_posts) { ?>
<?php foreach( $thumb_posts as $post ) {
echo '<div class="feature"><div class="thumbnail">
<a href="' . get_permalink($header_thumb->ID) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($header_thumb->ID,array(240,170)) . '</a></div>';
$url = get_permalink($post->ID);
$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$count = $json->$url->comments;
if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
$count = '0';
} elseif ( $count == 1 ) {
$count = '1';
} else {
$count .= '';
}
echo '<h3 class="title"> <a href="' . get_permalink($header_thumb->ID) . '#comments"     class="comments">' . $count . '</a> <a href="' . get_permalink($header_thumb->ID) . '"> ' . get_the_title($ID) . ' </a> </h3></div>';
} ?>
```

Which I did not write, but calls the facebook comment count of the random post with title and thumbnail.

Here is my problem... Once I place my second code AFTER this it throws off the count/image retrieval. However, if I place this code BEFORE everything works great.

```
<?php 
$thumb_posts = get_posts(array('category' => '6', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'numberposts' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' ));
if($thumb_posts) { 
?>

<?php 
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=20');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> | 
<span class="post-info"> <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'),
current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?> </span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my thought process, I need to somehow make it so the second code doesn't somehow throw off the first independent code.

Comment: Does PHP have a debugger you could use to examine which variables are being trampled over?

Comment: i'm betting on the `$post` when glueing random scripts together check there variable names

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. I'm sure I am doing things the cleanest just yet, but would I somehow create these two scripts into functions above the hook, and then later call them within the specified area?

Comment: Also, I edited my post because I didn't show the correct posting.

<?php 
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=20');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> | <span class="post-info"> <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?> </span></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>


That is the code that doesn't like the first block of code above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "pulling from the same parameters" due to this set of lines:

```
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=20');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
```

In order:

1. By doing `global $post`, you are hoisting a reference to the global variable `$post` set by Wordpress into your scope. `$post` represents the current post.
2. You then get a number of posts from WP and set it as `$myposts`. This is fine.
3. What is **NOT** fine, however, is that you're then looping over `$myposts` with as unique element `$post`. This last assignment causes Wordpress's global `$post` to be reset and corrupts all the rest.

Consider doing this instead:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=20');
foreach($myposts as $current_post) : 
?>
```

This does not modify the global scope at all, which is where Wordpress saves a few things.